# Is it possible to use DialogFlow to response in different language?

Tags: flutter, dialogflow-es, response

At starting the conversation, I want to ask if he can read Thai.
If He says "Yes" or "ใช่" then I will explain everything in Thai whatever he asks in Thai or English.
If He says "No" or "ไม่ใช่" then I will explain everything in English.
I gonna use Flutter to create this mobile app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to build multilanguage agents in dialog flow
[this might help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1vmLBRXJaA)

Comment: It seems I need to change my way of working. TY